# How to handle field select with search in selenium IDE?

Tags: css-selectors, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have 2 field with same element. I succeed in one field with this command:

```
Command:sendKeys | Target:css=div.Select-control input | Value: Brain${KEY_ENTER}
```

but I have problem in another field with same element.
I don't know to location another field with same element.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

If they both have the exact same locators, try using `:nth-of-type()` on the end of your locator to locate specific instances.

https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors In the section titled Choosing a specific match

Another option would to be to use a compound locator, based on a parent element unique to the section of the page each field is on

Comment: A more concrete example using information from the quesiton:
Target:css=div.Select-control input:nth-of-type(2)